# Retrieve Flickr photo title AND description using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

Annoyingly, the FlickrAPI provides the title and description of a photo in two separate methods. I'm having trouble getting the description of an image from Flickr and was wondering if you could highlight the error in my script.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < photos.photo.length; i++) {
          var descPhoto = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key="+API_KEY+"&photo_id="+photos.photo[i].id+"&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
          var descArr = [];

          $.getJSON(descPhoto, function(data) {
              var value = data.photo.description._content;
              descArr.push(value);
          });

          link = 'https://farm' + photos.photo[i].farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + photos.photo[i].server + '/' + photos.photo[i].id + '_' + photos.photo[i].secret + '_';

          title = this._htmlEscape( photos.photo[i].title );
          var lightbox = "lightbox";

          listItems += 
            '<li ' + 'class="' + liClassNoDots + '">' + 
            '<a href="' + link + self.options.imageSize + '.jpg" title="' + title + '" class="' + aClassNoDots + '" target="_blank" data-lightbox="' + lightbox + '">' + 
             <img alt="' + title + '" src="' + link + self.options.thumbnailSize +'.jpg"/>' +

            '<div class="hover-box">' +
              '<p>' + descArr[i] + '</p>' + 
              '<button class="box-button view">View larger</button>' +
              '<button class="box-button request">Request</button>' +
            '</div>';
          '</a>' + 
       '</li>';
  }
```

Getting the title is fine and I've checked by API string calls and they work in the address bar of my browser.

I've used `console.log()` and the array is printed out correctly and I'm getting the descriptions. However, in each `<p>` tag the script is returning `undefined` in each instance.

**However**, if I run the script through the debugger the parapgraph tags are populated with the descriptions. Can somebody help?!

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in following code::

```
..
$.getJSON(description, function(desc) {
    value = desc.photo[ i ].description._content;                          
});
```

the [service url](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html) returns `photo` object whereas you are using `photo` array, change to:

```
..
$.getJSON(description, function(desc) {
    value = desc.photo.description._content;
    console.log( value );                     
});
```

Comment: I've tried using the above solution but no success. Still doesn't return the description.

Comment: is your url to get photo information correct..? And what does console.log(value); return…?

Comment: The photo URL is correct yes. The console.log returns nothing into the firefox console. Using firebug `value=""` at all times in the script.